# If a sequence of quadratic forms converges pointwise, then does the associated sequence of matrices also converge?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, quadratic-forms, pointwise-convergence

Consider the sequence of functions $f_k : \mathbb N \times \mathbb R^n \to [0,\infty)$ defined as $f_k(x) = x^TP_kx$, where $P_k : \mathbb N \to \mathbb S_+^n$ is a sequence of symmetric and positive semi-definite $n \times n$ matrices. If $f_k$ converges pointwise to the function $f : \mathbb R^n \to [0,\infty)$ defined as $f(x) = x^TPx$, where $P \in \mathbb S_+^n$, then is it true that $P_k$ converges to $P$? I think that the answer is "yes", but I'm not sure how to complete the following proof:

To show that $P_k \to P$, we want to show that $\forall \varepsilon_2 > 0, \exists N_2 \in \mathbb N,k \geq N_2 \implies \|P_k - P\|_F < \varepsilon_2$, where $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm, such that $\|P_k - P\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \left|p_{ij}^{[k]} - p_{ij}\right|^2}$, where $p_{ij}^{[k]}$ is the $(i,j)$ element of $P_k$ and $p_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$ element of $P$.

Because $f_k = x^TP_kx$ converges pointwise to $f = x^TPx$, then $\forall x \in \mathbb R^n, \forall \varepsilon_1 > 0, \exists N_1 \in \mathbb N, k \geq N_1 \implies |x^T(P_k - P)x| < \varepsilon_1$. So, pick $x$ to be a vector of all $1$'s, such that
$$
\begin{align}
|x^T(P_k - P)x| &= \left|\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (p_{ij}^{[k]} - p_{ij})\right| \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \left|p_{ij}^{[k]} - p_{ij}\right|
\end{align}
$$
However, I'm not sure how to then pick $\varepsilon_1$ (to get the corresponding $N_1$) and then relate $|x^T(P_k - P)x|$ to $\|P_k - P\|_F$ above via $\varepsilon_2$ to get the corresponding $N_2$, so I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Clarification : do you *assume* that $P$ is also symmetric positive-definite, or is that not assumed? Note that you used this assumption in your calculations, since the identity $p_{ij}+p_{ji} = 2p_{ij}$ was used in your answer. To me, if $P$ is not assumed to be symmetric positive-definite, then that step doesn't work (although the diagonal entries converge).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer $P$ is assumed to be symmetric positive semi-definite, as indicated by “…where $P \in \mathbb S_+^n$”.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f_k(e_i)$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th unit vector which turns out to be equal to $p_{i,i}^{(k)}$. Thus by assumtion $\lim_k p_{i,i}^{(k)}=\lim_kf_k(e_i)=f(e_i)=p_{i,i}$. Next for $i\not=j$ consider $f_k(e_i+e_j)$ which equals $2p_{i,j}^{(k)}$, and argue as above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please expand a bit more on the "argue as above" part? I found that $f_k(e_i + e_j) = e_i^TP_ke_i + 2e_i^TP_ke_j + e_j^TP_ke_j = p_{ii}^{[k]} + 2p_{ij}^{[k]} + p_{jj}^{[k]}$ and not $2p_{ij}^{[k]}$ as you wrote.

Comment: Actually, I think the following is what you meant (correct me if I'm wrong): first, compute $f_k(e_i) = p_{ii}^{[k]}$ for each $i = 1,\dots,n$. Then, compute the limit of both sides of these equation to get $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(e_i) = f(e_i) = \lim_{k \to \infty} p_{ii}^{[k]}$. Because $f(e_i) = p_{ii}$, then $\lim_{k \to \infty} p_{ii}^{[k]} = p_{ii}$...

Comment: ...Next, compute $f_k(e_i + e_j) = p_{ii}^{[k]} + 2p_{ij}^{[k]} + p_{jj}^{[k]}$ and compute the limit on both sides to get $$\begin{align} \lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(e_i + e_j) &= f(e_i + e_j) \\ &= \lim_{k \to \infty} [p_{ii}^{[k]} + 2p_{ij}^{[k]} + p_{jj}^{[k]}] \\ &= \lim_{k \to \infty} p_{ii}^{[k]} + \lim_{k \to \infty} 2p_{ij}^{[k]} + \lim_{k \to \infty} p_{jj}^{[k]} \\ &= p_{ii} + \lim_{k \to \infty} 2p_{ij}^{[k]} + p_{jj}\end{align}$$...

Comment: ...Finally, because $f(e_i + e_j) = p_{ii} + 2p_{ij} + p_{jj} = p_{ii} + \lim_{k \to \infty} 2p_{ij}^{[k]} + p_{jj}$, then $\lim_{k \to \infty} 2p_{ij}^{[k]} = 2p_{ij}$, as desired.

Comment: Of course you are right. The diagonal elements have to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of clarity, here is a complete answer based on @JensSchwaiger's answer.

Because $f_k \to f$ pointwise, then $f_k(e_i) \to f(e_i)$, where $e_i$ is the vector of all $0$'s except the $i$th position, where there is a $1$ (i.e. $e_i$ is the $i$th [standard basis vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis)). That is,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(e_i) = f(e_i) &\implies \lim_{k \to \infty} e_i^TP_ke_i = e_i^TPe_i = p_{ii} \\
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, because $f_k \to f$ pointwise, then $f_k(e_i + e_j) \to f(e_i + e_j)$, such that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(e_i + e_j) = f(e_i + e_j) &\implies \lim_{k \to \infty} e_i^TP_ke_i + 2e_i^TP_ke_j + e_j^TP_ke_j = e_i^TPe_i + 2e_i^TPe_j + e_j^TPe_j \\
&\implies \lim_{k \to \infty} p_{ii}^{[k]} + 2p_{ij}^{[k]} + p_{jj}^{[k]} = p_{ii} + 2p_{ij} + p_{jj} \\
&\implies \lim_{k \to \infty} p_{ii}^{[k]} + \lim_{k \to \infty} 2p_{ij}^{[k]} + \lim_{k \to \infty} p_{jj}^{[k]} = p_{ii} + 2p_{ij} + p_{jj} \\
&\implies p_{ii} + \lim_{k \to \infty} 2p_{ij}^{[k]} + p_{jj} = p_{ii} + 2p_{ij} + p_{jj} \\
&\implies \lim_{k \to \infty} 2p_{ij}^{[k]} = 2p_{ij} \\
&\implies \lim_{k \to \infty} p_{ij}^{[k]} = p_{ij}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $\forall (i,j) \in \{1,\dots,n\}^2, \forall \varepsilon_3 > 0,\exists N_3^{[ij]} \in \mathbb N, k \geq N_3^{[ij]} \implies \left|p_{ij}^{[k]} - p_{ij}\right| < \varepsilon_3$. For convenience, for every $\varepsilon_3 > 0$, let $N_3 = \max\left\{N_3^{[ij]} \mid (i,j) \in \{1,\dots,n\}^2\right\}$ (note that $N_3^{[ij]}$ is implicitly a function of $\varepsilon_3$ for each $(i,j)$), such that $\forall \varepsilon_3 > 0, \exists N_3 \in \mathbb N, \forall (i,j) \in \{1,\dots,n\}^2, k \geq N_3 \implies \left|p_{ij}^{[k]} - p_{ij}\right| < \varepsilon_3$.

Finally, the proof proceeds as follows. Fix any $\varepsilon_2 > 0$ and choose $\varepsilon_3 > 0$ such that
$$
\varepsilon_3 < \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2} \varepsilon_2^2}
$$
and get the corresponding $N_3 \in \mathbb N$. Then, let $N_2 \geq N_3$ and suppose that $k \geq N_2$, such that
$$
\begin{align}
\|P_k - P\|_F &= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \left|p_{ij}^{[k]} - p_{ij}\right|^2} \\
&< \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2} \varepsilon_2^2}\right)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2} \varepsilon_2^2} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}\varepsilon_2^2 \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n 1} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}\varepsilon_2^2 n^2} \\
&= \sqrt{\varepsilon_2^2} \\
&= \varepsilon_2
\end{align}
$$
as desired.